# Blazor Page Bootstrap model that is passed from the parent component doesn't show up

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am currently trying to find my way around Blazor Pages.

At the moment I am trying to open a bootstrap model when clicking on a button.

I tried to implement this with a child component (WorkoutsDetail.razor).

However, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, The properties of the model are bind to the input controls using bind-value.

Does anyone have a tip on what else I need to pay attention to?

This is the page where the Button (AddTask) should open the model

```
@page "/workouts"
@using Tracker.Data
@using Tracker.Services
@inject IWorkoutsListService service
<h3>Workout Plans</h3>
@if (workoutsNames == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var workouts in workoutsNames)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@workouts.Name</td>                  
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit">Edit</button></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" /></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
<div>
    <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#workoutsModal" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Task" @onclick="(() => InitializeTaskObject())" />
</div>

<WorkoutsDetail WorkoutObject=workoutObject></WorkoutsDetail>

@code {
    List<Tracker.Data.Workouts> workoutsNames;
    Tracker.Data.Workouts workoutObject = new Tracker.Data.Workouts();
    

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        workoutsNames = await service.Get();
    }

    private void InitializeTaskObject()
    {
        workoutObject = new Tracker.Data.Workouts();
        
    }
}
```

This is where I set the Model

```
@using Tracker.Data
@using Tracker.Services
@inject IWorkoutsListService service
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="workoutsModal" style=" display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Workout Detail</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <EditForm Model="@WorkoutObject" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="workoutName">Workout Name</label>
                        <input type="hidden" @bind-value="@WorkoutObject.Id" />
                        <InputText id="name" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@WorkoutObject.Name" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </EditForm>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Tracker.Data.Workouts WorkoutObject { get; set; }

    List<string> TaskStatusList = new List<string>() { "New", "In Progress", "Completed" };

    private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: There are several pure C# alternatives to using the Bootstrap modal which requires bootstrap js and changing the browser DOM outside Blazor.  Search "Blazor Modal".

Answer (score 0):

The way that I achieved this is by using the IJSRuntime and calling the bootstrap method "modal.show" on the desired model and "modal.hide" when I no longer need it:

I started by importing the JSInterop namespace

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
```

Then I used the InvokeVoidAsync method to call "modal.show"

```
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("modal.show", "ConfirmationModal");
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="@Id" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">@Title</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" @onclick="OnCloseClick">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Body
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            @Actions
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the reason why  the id is set to @id is because I created a blazor component and reused it throughout by site

Comment: This solution modifies the browser DOM outside Blazor i.e. you create a mismatch between the Renderer's version of the DOM and the Browser's.  You most often get away with it, but there are times and circumstances where you don't, and when that happens it can take a lot of time trying to work out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can (but don't need to) use JSInterop to open or close modals, when using data-attributes.  I use this in my blazor project exactly as you have attempted to do - apart from the following differences:

1. If you are using the latest version of Bootstrap (V5) - please ensure your data attributes are named correctly:

   `data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#workoutsModal"`

If you leave out the -bs- with Bootstrap V5 it won't work - even though it did work with earlier versions.  I also note your modal seems to be based on an older version of Bootstrap. Just ensure that you are following the conventions of the version actually included in your `<head>` section.

2. I don't have `display: block` set for my modal (I don't need any additional styles in order for this to work).

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, it works for me.

**Hope you added bootstrap related javascript link in index.html**

also remove

> style=" display: block;

[image: Gif]

Comment: If you want to Create a Reusable, **JavaScript-Free** Blazor Modal. Then please refer [this.](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/creating-a-reusable-javascript-free-blazor-modal) by Chris Sainty